# Delocalize netsh output

Tags: windows, netsh

I was wondering if anyone knew of a way (or if it is even possible) to get the "non-localized" (English) output of netsh on an OS that has a different language installed.

i.e. instead of receiving something like:

```
Reservierte URL: https://*:5358/
Benutzer: VORDEFINIERT\Benutzer
    Abhören: Yes
    Delegieren: No
Benutzer: NT-AUTORITÄT\LOKALER DIENST
    Abhören: Yes
    Delegieren: No
    SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;BU)(A;;GX;;;LS)
```

On a German system, I'd like to be able to get the "English" version, something along the lines of:

```
Reserved URL: https://*:5358/
User: BUILTIN\Users
    Listen: Yes
    Delegate: No
User: NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE
    Listen: Yes
    Delegate: No
    SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;BU)(A;;GX;;;LS)
```

Is this possible?

P.S. I've tried changing the code page of the console window / console process to 437 which to my knowledge should be English, but I had no luck there.

Comment: And what exactly might your ultimate goal in this be?

Comment: Being able to actually parse the output correctly in a script / program.

Comment: You’re better off with APIs. Good thing there’s an [API for that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851161/net-or-win32-equivalent-of-netsh-http-add-urlacl-command). Technically, there’s even an [actual app](http://httpsysconfig.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Thanks for that link - Been looking for an API for ages, wasn't able to find any until now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best answer was "There's an API for that" - Which is essentially what I was looking for.

Thanks to Daniel B.

> You’re better off with APIs. Good thing there’s an [API for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851161/net-or-win32-equivalent-of-netsh-http-add-urlacl-command). Technically, there’s even an [actual app](https://httpsysconfig.codeplex.com/).